# How to enable Yii2 backjob?

Tags: php, yii2

I have used and followed [yii backjob](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/backjob/)

When I setting below on application config I'm getting an error

```
'preload' => array(
    'background'
),
```

Error

```
An internal server error occurred.
```

**Note:** Mainly I'm looking for When I'm executing my API Call it should not wait for API Response. If you have any other idea please share with me.

Comment: isn't that extension for yii 1.1 ?

Comment: Yes! Works with Yii-1.1.14 and up. But my application version Yii2